# unable to access Azure file share from a windows service running in Azure VM

Tags: azure, fileshare

I created a Azure File Share. Created a Azure Domain Service and made my Azure VM as a member of this AD Service. I am able to mount the File share in windows by mapping a drive. But the same file share is inaccessible from a Windows service running in the same Azure VM

Comment: What is the Service Account for the Windows Service?

Comment: the application account

Comment: And which account is that?  A local account?  A built-in account?  A domain account?

Comment: It is a local system account

Comment: Which one?  And how are you attempting to access the share in the service?  Not by drive letter, right?

Comment: windows service is a local system account. yes not by Drive letter . By the File share path given in azure File share

Comment: Which local system account?

Comment: when I right clicked the windows service and checked for properties , there is no specific user log on. Log on as local system account is selected

Comment: should I login to the Azure VM with AD domain service user account